# React leaflet and react-leaflet-draw

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-draw

I'm trying to implement the draw functions on leaflet map. I've created a new app with only react-leaflet installed, using npx create-react-app and the following packages installed:

- npm install react react-dom leaflet
- npm install react-leaflet

At this point, I've started the application and everything is working fine: the map is correctly visualized with a marker in the middle.

Then I've added the react-leaflet-draw package, with npm install react-leaflet-draw, and import it in the page I get the following error:

```
./node_modules/react-leaflet-draw/dist/esm/EditControl.js
Attempted import error: 'MapControl' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'
```

This is the full code:

```
import './App.css';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, MapControl } from 'react-leaflet'
import L from 'leaflet';
import icon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png';
import iconShadow from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png';
import iconRetina from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png';

import 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css';
import { EditControl } from "react-leaflet-draw";


delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;
L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconRetinaUrl: iconRetina,
  iconUrl: icon,
  shadowUrl: iconShadow
})



function App() {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={10} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
    </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What's the issue with this package? Does it work on react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check this [github issue](https://github.com/alex3165/react-leaflet-draw/issues/87) you will conclude that `react-leaflet-draw` is only compatible with `react-leaflet` versions **2.x** and not with versions **3.x**.

As a result it does not work in your case because you are using react-leaflet version **3.x**.

If you downgrade to versions **2.x** it should work as expected

Last but not least you do not need to import `MapControl` as it is not required from the package. You only need to import

```
import { EditControl } from "react-leaflet-draw"
```

as you already did. `MapControl` is used internally in the library and probably something has changed in the newer version, that is why you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add `MapControl` to your import:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, MapControl } from 'react-leaflet'
```

Comment: Done it, but still the same error. I forgot to paste the code where actually I added it